# Indesign data merge on 2 pages with different layout

Tags: adobe-indesign

I would like to have a two page Indesign document. First page has text + image and second page has 2 images. The images should come from a csv file that gets data merged with the Indesign document. Is this achievable. I have only been able to do a data merge when I have one page, but then all pages have the same layout. Is this possible and how do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Want to do by coding?

Comment: Why not? Coding shouldn't be a problem. How do I do it with coding?

Comment: Good question. I will start by searching some API to manipulate the indesign. Maybe a good soul know any and answer.

Comment: @Bisconcini I found a work around for the problem. I am going to work with an XML file. An XML file offers a little bit more flexibility. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.   Xml is the way.

Comment: any change you could share your solution?

Comment: Datamerge can be achieved on two pages. A solution here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/2969615#2969615 Otherwise XML is a really convenient solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to work with XML files (File -> Import XML) instead of CSV. You can make any type of document and put XML objects in text fields, images, ... XML is much more flexible than CSV.

Answer (score 0):

a CSV field that is named @photo1 will link to a file location

```
column F (for instance)
    @photo1
    c:\foldername\filename.jpg
    c:\folder2name\subfolder\otherfile.png
    f:\file3.tiff
```

Comment: I hard returned and indented the column example but the stupid site crunched all the text. sorry